# Find the source of "the app you are trying to install is not a Microsoft-verified app" dialog

Tags: windows, windows-11, microsoft-smartscreen

I occasionally get his dialog in Windows 11 business 22H2

[image: smart screen]

It happens at random and I don't trigger it myself. It may be something malicious but it just might just be an app I intentionally installed, which has a faulty update mechanism. I already ran a complete defender check without a result.

There are plenty solutions out there how to avoid this dialog by just disabling it, which is not what I want. I do **NOT** want to click on `Install anyway` or disable this warning entirely via `Settings > Apps > Apps & Features`

I just want to see which command triggered the dialog. Maybe it's fine and I don't want to reset my computer for nothing.

Is there a a way to show the source of this dialog? I already checked event log application and system and didn't find anything interesting.

Comment: Without knowing what the application is, we cannot really tell you, how to prevent it. Your edition of Windows suggests this is a corporate machine. Have you asked your IT Administrator for assistance?

Answer (score 1):

#### Is there a a way to show the source of this dialog?

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx)'s "Find Window's Process" feature (the crosshairs on the toolbar of the Process Explorer window). Click and drag it over the window you want to identify, and Process Explorer will highlight the process it belongs to.

Answer (score -1):

This message may mean that you have set Windows to accept only
applications from the Microsoft Store.

What to do:

For this message, just click the "Install anyway" button,
and the install should proceed. This may also show
which app is being updated.

For Windows, run *Settings > Apps > Apps & Features*.
Under "Choose where to get apps", change the setting to "Anywhere".

Comment: Why the downvote ?

Comment: Even if my answer did not solve the poster's problem, it's still useful for people that have the same error message but for the reason outlined in my answer. Downvoting an answer that could be useful to others is not very nice.